# Identify who sent me Facebook messages

Tags: facebook-messenger

Somebody has messaged me and I am not able to find his name as all messages are showing his name as `facebook user` and profile is also not opening.

How do I find details of this messenger?

Comment: Could it be that the user account no longer exists?

Answer (score 1):

If it shows as "Facebook User" this means that the account no longer exists.

You can use your pointer to rollover the message summary to see the Facebook ID that used to be associated with it.

[image: Old Account]